# How to detect when Turbo Stream broadcast is established?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, turbo-rails

In my Rails view I call turbo_stream_from view helper to establish turbo stream web socket connection:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from :my_broadcast %>
```

Is there a way for know when the web socket connection was established using JavaScript in the browser? Does @hotwired/turbo-rails JavaScript library allow to submit a callback that will be called when the WebSocket is established?

Answer (score 0):

The `connected` attribute is added to the `<turbo-cable-stream-source>` HTML element when connection is established. See https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/pull/430 and https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/434.